# SVG tspan transform skew

Tags: svg

I'm looking for a way to skew a `tspan` with `transform="skewX(-45)"`, but it only seems to work on the parent `text` as a whole. The problem is a want surrounding `tspan`s to be unaffected by the skew, only the middle one. The reason I don't want to use multiple `text`s is that I want the flow calculations to be done for me instead of me positioning the `text`s manually (so future font change doesn't throw the text flow off). I also need the following text spans to be flown with respect to the width of the slanted text span, not the original one.

Is there a way to apply `transform` to a `tspan` only or can this be done with multiple `text`s while preserving the text flow?

Comment: There is no transform allowed on `tspan`. The issue was recently discussed for the SVG 2 spec (in conjunction with `textPath` and `a` elements), but ultimately [rejected](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/210).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [ccprog's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345913/svg-tspan-transform-skew#comment75696204_44345913), there are some [rendering issues / complications](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/210) with using [transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) on [`<tspan>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan).

Here are the available [**attributes on `<tspan>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan#Attributes):

[image]

You *might* be able to fit your needs by combining `rotate`, `dx`, & `dy` to various effects.  Some people have had luck wrapping the `<text>` element inside of an `<a>` as it [does allow transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a#Global_attributes).